# How to have bot send specified user a DM?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to create a warning command that DMs the specified user to notify them. Here is the specific code I'm trying to use:

```
    const user = await client.users
      .fetch(interaction.options.getString("user"), false)
      .catch(() => null);
    console.log(interaction.options.getString("user"));
    const embed = new MessageEmbed()
      .setColor("#FCE100")
      .setTitle(`⚠️ Warning!`)
      .setDescription(`${interaction.options.getString("warning")}`);
    await user.send({ embeds: embed }).catch(() => {
      interaction.channel.send(
        "Error: user not found"
      );
    });
```

The `getString` for `user` is correctly getting the user, as I've tested from `console.log()`. I can only assume the syntax is somehow wrong, although I can't seem to find the correct way to do this. The only error I'm getting is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'send')
```

Comment: Could you show what `user` outputs? Because you could be using [InteractionOptions#getUser](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/CommandInteractionOptionResolver?scrollTo=getUser) instead which would be significantly simpler I'd imagine, also which line is the error on? Just double checking

Comment: Oh nevermind I just noticed something, you can't use .catch() with await since it doesn't return a promise, but the promise's response, which means the error should be on user.send. use try-catch, but yeah, still show what user outputs please

Comment: Seems that your `.catch` runs and returns `null`. Try removing the `.catch`

Comment: @MrMythical removing `.catch` returns a new error: `DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body
user_id: Value "<@!155474254249459713>" is not snowflake.`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `.getString()`.
[CommandInteractionOptionResolver#getString()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/CommandInteractionOptionResolver?scrollTo=getUser) does it for you.
**Make sure that you have the user option type set to `"USER"` before doing the code below.**

```js
const user = interaction.options.getUser("user");
// ...
```